# Early hyphenation library - 80s - 90s

Tags: hyphenation, typography

I recall back in the late 1980s and perhaps early 1990s a library that was available in a number of forms that achieved excellent hyphenation in many/most languages.

I seem to remember it was called the xxx and yyy hyphenation libraries but sadly my age is getting the better of me and I cannot remember its name.

Anyone?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for the [Knuth–Liang hyphenation algorithm](http://tug.org/docs/liang/), implemented in many programming languages.

Comment: It could well have been based on that paper - the dates work - but it was distributed under a name that I will know when I see it. Do you recall a real implementation of it back then?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Naw, the libary name will surely vary by programming language, eh?

Comment: If I recall correctly they released the library as an 8086 .obj which effectively covered most systems back then. They implemented most European languages as separate libraries. This was back in the IBM PC dual-floppy/XT/AT days.

Comment: Could it have been Purdy & Mackintosh (or spelling variants). I cannot find any google references but it rings a bell.